# How to get the closest point to the map on the shapefile in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, mapping

The red dots represents the points in the shape file. I want to find point B (closest point on the shapefile to point A). The B might not be one from the given set of points in the shapefile (as we are finding the closest one.) Any solution to solve thus using Python? I want the coordinates of B.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a linestring from all the points in the shapefile (all the red points in your image). Then I would use the `nearest points` method from the `shapely` library to return the point in the linestring that is nearest to point A. The `list_of_points` variable in the code below is a list of point you have extracted from the shapefile.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

pt_a = Point(coordinates of A)
ls = LineString([Point(point.x, point.y) for point in list_of_points)
nearest_pts = [pt for pt in nearest_points(pt_a, ls)
```

The `nearest_pts` variable as result will give you a list of 2 points: point A and point B. You can extract the coordinates using `point.x` and `point.y`.

Comment: Didn't know about nearest_points methods before. Works like a charm. Thanks.